Query for WordPress user ID
Is there a way for search results to show the WordPress user ID for each user?  I can't seem to find a way to include it in SearchKit results, or in export-to-csv fields, or in Search Builder, etc.  The only way I've found is to use raw SQL:
SELECT c.id, c.display_name, um.uf_id
FROM civicrm_contact c LEFT JOIN civicrm_uf_match um ON c.id=um.contact_id
WHERE c.id IN (
    SELECT contact_id
    FROM civicrm_group_contact
    WHERE group_id IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM civicrm_group
        WHERE name='The Group Name'
    )
    AND status='Added'
);

I'm using CiviCRM 5.76.2 on WordPress 6.6.2 (self-hosted).

Join on contact user accounts and add the cms id to the columns.


I'm trying to get the CMS ID for everybody in a search result (or Null/empty if they have none), not limit to only people with a CMS ID.

Oops, sorry, I see that this works quite well for my use case, I missed the "(optional)" part of that query.  Thanks!
